# Fine-grained Authentication with RESTlet

Tags: java, authentication, restlet

I want to expose a resource using RESTlet with a fine-grained authentication. My `ServerResource` should be accessable via `GET` only for authenticated members (using BASIC Authentication). However, requests using `POST` should be available also for callers without  any authentication.

In order to clearify: 
http://path/myapp/user should allow anyone to register using `POST`, but only registered members should be able to `GET` a list of all users.

I'm unfortunately not much into RESTlet and I only find examples using coarser authentication for whole `Restlet`s or `Router`s.

So how do I enable optional authentication for resources and check them on a per-method level?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To do basic authentication in RESTlet 2.0 (I assume you're using 2.0 since you mention `ServerResource`), you need to use a `ChallengeAuthenticator`. If this is configured with `optional = true` then authentication will only be requested if you invoke `ChallengeAuthenticator.challenge()`.

You can create your application with an `authenticate()` method, and call this whenever you need access to a resource to be secured:

Application:

```
package example;

import org.restlet.*;
import org.restlet.data.ChallengeScheme;
import org.restlet.routing.Router;
import org.restlet.security.*;

public class ExampleApp extends Application {

    private ChallengeAuthenticator authenticatior;

    private ChallengeAuthenticator createAuthenticator() {
        Context context = getContext();
        boolean optional = true;
        ChallengeScheme challengeScheme = ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC;
        String realm = "Example site";

        // MapVerifier isn't very secure; see docs for alternatives
        MapVerifier verifier = new MapVerifier();
        verifier.getLocalSecrets().put("user", "password".toCharArray());

        ChallengeAuthenticator auth = new ChallengeAuthenticator(context, optional, challengeScheme, realm, verifier) {
            @Override
            protected boolean authenticate(Request request, Response response) {
                if (request.getChallengeResponse() == null) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return super.authenticate(request, response);
                }
            }
        };

        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        this.authenticatior = createAuthenticator();

        Router router = new Router();
        router.attach("/user", UserResource.class);

        authenticatior.setNext(router);
        return authenticatior;
    }

    public boolean authenticate(Request request, Response response) {
        if (!request.getClientInfo().isAuthenticated()) {
            authenticatior.challenge(response, false);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Resource:

```
package example;

import org.restlet.data.MediaType;
import org.restlet.representation.EmptyRepresentation;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.representation.StringRepresentation;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class UserResource extends ServerResource {

    @Override
    public Representation get() {
        ExampleApp app = (ExampleApp) getApplication();
        if (!app.authenticate(getRequest(), getResponse())) {
            // Not authenticated
            return new EmptyRepresentation();
        }

        // Generate list of users
        // ...
    }     

    @Override
    public Representation post(Representation entity) {
        // Handle post
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, this looks promising. However, I have some problems getting your code to work. For instance, there is no `getSubject()` method for ClientInfo (I'm using 2.0m7). Also, I'm not sure if your `authenticate()` method is correct?

Comment: I was using an earlier snapshot; I've updated the examples to work with 2.0m7.

Comment: Thanks, again, now the code compiles and POST is always available. Unfortunately, GET is never. No matter if I provide no, wrong or correct BASIC credentials, I always get a 401.

Comment: I've tried it again and the example works for me using RESTlet 2.0m7. Are you running the example, or trying to adapt it to your code?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, your code works fine! Thank you very much for your sustainable help!

Comment: Thank you for the example, it was very useful!

Just one question: why are you overriding the authenticator to check if the challengeResponse is null?

Comment: Thanks for you code sample indeed! it very useful. I do have a question anyway , is your "ExampleApp's authenticate(...)" method really necessary? as you have a "authentcator" defined has predecessor of the "router" in createInRoot()... so i guess it already filters all requests before they can be even reached the router, hence the server's resource...

Answer (score 5):

I'm presently using Restlet v2.0.10.

The problem with `ChallengeAuthenticator.isOptional()` is that it's all or nothing. An alternative to the answer provided by @sea36 above is to override `ChallengeAuthenticator.beforeHandle()` to either perform authentication or skip it based on request method. For example, the resource below will only require authentication when the GET method is used.

Application:

```
package example;

import org.restlet.*;
import org.restlet.data.ChallengeScheme;
import org.restlet.routing.Router;
import org.restlet.security.ChallengeAuthenticator;
import org.restlet.security.MapVerifier;

public class ExampleApp extends Application {

    private ChallengeAuthenticator createAuthenticator() {
        Context context = getContext();
        ChallengeScheme challengeScheme = ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC;
        String realm = "Example site";

        // MapVerifier isn't very secure; see docs for alternatives
        MapVerifier verifier = new MapVerifier();
        verifier.getLocalSecrets().put("user", "password".toCharArray());

        ChallengeAuthenticator authOnGet = new ChallengeAuthenticator(context, challengeScheme, realm) {
            @Override
            protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {
                if (request.getMethod() == Method.GET)
                    return super.beforeHandle(request, response);

                response.setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_OK);
                return CONTINUE;
            }
        };

        return authOnGet;
    }

    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        ChallengeAuthenticator userResourceWithAuth = createAuthenticator();
        userResourceWithAuth.setNext(UserResource.class);

        Router router = new Router();
        router.attach("/user", userResourceWithAuth);

        return router;
    }

}
```

Resource:

```
package example;

import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.Post;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class UserResource extends ServerResource {

    @Get
    public Representation listUsers() {
        // retrieve list of users and generate response
        // ...
    }     

    @Post
    public void register(Representation entity) {
        // handle post
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that this example applies the policy of authenticating on GET only to the `UserResource` and not other resources handled by the router.