# How to make an exception for ChallengeAuthenticator

Tags: authentication, restlet

I am using Restlet Authentication. I create my own Verifier.

```
ChallengeAuthenticator guard = 
  new ChallengeAuthenticator(getContext(),ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "my realm");

guard.setVerifier(new CaupenneServerVerifier());

guard.setNext(aRouter);
```

aRouter attaches all the resources. But I only want to guard some of the resources, not all of them. Does anybody know how I can do this? Is there a way in Restlet Authentication to make an exception?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the answer to this SO question:

[Fine-grained Authentication with RESTlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217418/fine-grained-authentication-with-restlet)